# Moving the position of an arrow in XY-pic

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

Any arrow in XY-pic is on a line which goes through the CENTER of a box, and points to the CENTER of another one. Is it possible to change SEPARETELY (the problem lies here!) the starting position and the arriving position? Of course, it is possible to shift an arrow. But this is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The manual sugests the following solution, eg,`\ar[]!<1ex,-2ex>;[ul]!<-3ex,1ex>`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine! You could have said RTFM, and you didn't... A. L.

Comment: I wish I'd know this years ago! I've had problems with ugly diagrams because of large expressions at nodes...