# xy-pic: moving start and end of bent arrow

Tags: xy-pic

I would like to improve the following Xy-pic drawing by putting the beginning of the arrow centered under the $x$ and its end centered under $f_u(x) u$:

```
\xymatrix@R=6pt{
    E \ar[r]^-{f_u} & \K \ar[r]^-{h_u} & E \\
    x \ar@{|->}[r] \ar@/_1.5pc/[rr]_-{\pi = h_u\circ f_u} & f_u(x) \ar@{|->}[r] & f_u(x)u
}
```

I read this answer: [Xy-pic moving the position of an arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34475/moving-the-position-of-an-arrow-in-xy-pic) but I can't understand how to apply it to my case in the `\ar@/_1.5pc/[rr]_-{\pi = h_u\circ f_u}` portion of code...

Any idea?

### EDIT:

 The MWE before tip:

```
\documentclass[francais,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pb-diagram}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

Try...

\[
\shorthandoff{;:!?}
\xymatrix@R=6pt{
    E \ar[r]^-{f_u} & \mathbb{K} \ar[r]^-{h_u} & E \\
    x \ar@{|->}[r] \ar@(_,_)[rr]_-{\pi = h_u\circ f_u} & f_u(x) \ar@{|->}[r] & f_u(x)u
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's wrong with my "$" (latex)??

Comment: Please post complete-but-minimal code rather than a snippet.

Comment: We don't have TeX interpretation on this site -- too often we talk about the TeX source rather than the ouput.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by changing the arrow bend modifier on the `[rr]` arrow.

(See p.42 in [the reference manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/xypic/xyrefer.pdf) ).

```
\documentclass[border=0.5]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=6pt{
    E \ar[r]^-{f_u} & K \ar[r]^-{h_u} & E \\
    x \ar@{|->}[r] \ar@(_,_)[rr]_-{\pi = h_u\circ f_u} & f_u(x) \ar@{|->}[r] & f_u(x)u
}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure it looks any better though:

[image]

If you call `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}`, the diagram becomes

[image]

Comment: Without the `cmtip` option, tips on bent arrows are awful; slightly less so on straight arrows.

Comment: OK, thanks, it's almost perfect, except that the bend is to large (I chose 1.5pc after several tries... ;)). How can I mix the bending control and this modifier, if possible? Otherwise, how can I change the bend with only the modifier?

Comment: @egreg: how can I call this option? Where do I have to put it (e.g. to which package is it related?) ?

Comment: @biblio `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}`

Comment: OK, but I don't see any difference (what? it's not magical??), so I guess there are commands to add somewhere...?

Comment: @biblio The difference is in the better arrow tips, you can see the added image. You need to rerun LaTeX, of course.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=6pt]
E \arrow[r,"f_u"] & K \arrow[r,"h_u"] & E \\
x \arrow[r,mapsto]
  \arrow[rr,swap,out=-45,in=-135,"\pi = h_u\circ f_u"] &
  f_u(x) \arrow[r,mapsto] & f_u(x)u
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thnks but it doesn't answer my question which is: how to put start and end of arrow centered under the scalar and its image? If I change the angles, the start and end move closer and it's quite the same my first try without the (_,_) modifier... Or maybe I was wrong somewhere?

Comment: By the way, I can't see the image, I have a "enter image description here", and when I click on the link, the server answers "unreachable"... Any explanation?

Comment: @biblio Apparently you can't momentarily reach Imgur, try again later.

Comment: OK, it seems it depends on the computer...